# How can I read variables in XML using volley

Tags: android

I'm trying read this XML using volley

```
<transcript>
<text start="4.454" dur="3.571">
Keep watching this video to find out what’s coming in Clash Royale Season 2.
</text>
<text start="8.742" dur="2.119">What’s up? I’m Drew from the Clash Royale team</text>
<text start="10.928" dur="3.637">
and I’m here to tell you all about Clash Royale Season 2: Shipwrecked!
</text>
<text start="15.332" dur="1.351">We are shipwrecked</text>
<text start="16.75" dur="2.186">on the conveniently-named Shipwreck Island.</text>
<text start="19.086" dur="1.234">This is a brand-new arena,</text>
<text start="20.387" dur="2.486">
where you’ll fight most of your battles in Season 2.
</text>
<text start="24.458" dur="2.719">Pass Royale has 35 new reward tiers to unlock.</text>
<text start="27.477" dur="2.286">Keeping with the summer vibes of Shipwreck Island,</text>
<text start="29.83" dur="1.368">we have a new tower skin.</text>
<text start="31.398" dur="2.736">
The Sandcastle is the unique tower skin for Season 2.
</text>
<text start="34.301" dur="2.653">This tower skin can be unlocked at reward tier 30.</text>
<text start="37.471" dur="2.169">The Season 2 emote is the first King emote</text>
<text start="39.723" dur="2.135">since we launched Clash Royale in 2016.</text>
<text start="42.009" dur="2.219">These rewards will only be available this season.</text>
<text start="44.428" dur="2.953">
As always, there is a guaranteed Legendary in tier 35.
</text>
<text start="47.781" dur="2.986">Earn chests, gold and more, with Pass Royale!</text>
<text start="52.636" dur="2.903">
Season 2 will have several new challenges for you to enjoy.
</text>
<text start="65.999" dur="3.604">
Unlock cards, chests, a new emote and more from these challenges.
</text>
<text start="71.488" dur="3.12">
Fisherman, the newest card, is now available for everybody.
</text>
<text start="74.908" dur="1.485">Trophy Road has been updated,</text>
<text start="76.46" dur="3.286">
so that these cards can be unlocked at certain trophies.
</text>
<text start="80.247" dur="1.952">Good luck on the Season 2 Trophy Road.</text>
<text start="84.234" dur="3.27">
Also coming in Season 2, we have a bunch of new balance changes.
</text>
<text start="88.038" dur="2.386">The Magic Archer is getting a big damage buff,</text>
<text start="90.524" dur="3.487">with +16%, and a small hit speed nerf.</text>
<text start="94.328" dur="3.236">
The latest card, Fisherman, is getting a hitpoints buff.
</text>
<text start="97.948" dur="3.186">And he’s also getting a buff to his anchor range.</text>
<text start="101.268" dur="4.121">
P.E.K.K.A is getting a hitpoint nerf, but also a melee range buff.
</text>
<text start="106.406" dur="4.021">
Our favorite elixir-guzzling Lumberjack is getting a hit speed nerf.
</text>
<text start="111.261" dur="2.97">Barbarian Barrel is getting a 15% damage nerf.</text>
<text start="114.464" dur="4.021">
And finally, Valkyrie will no longer outrange long-ranged melee troops.
</text>
<text start="120.387" dur="2.869">
That’s it. Keep an eye out for Season 2: Shipwrecked,
</text>
<text start="123.323" dur="1.702">coming to Clash Royale on August 5th.</text>
<text start="125.192" dur="2.686">
Remember to like this video, subscribe for more news
</text>
<text start="127.944" dur="2.42">and we’ll see you on Shipwreck Island!</text>
</transcript>
```

*Volley Code*

```
StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.w("salahhh", response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.w("salahhh", "error");
                    }
                }
        );
```

*The result will be like above but I want without read (text , start , dur , transcript etc...) I want read only variables for example like this*

1- Keep watching this video to find out what’s coming in Clash Royale Season 2. 
2- What’s up? I’m Drew from the Clash Royale team 
etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use something like XmlPullParser for parsing xml response.

First Convert your response string to xml:

```
  XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser();
  InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  List<YourObject> object = new ArrayList<>();
  object.addAll(xmlParser.parseFeed(inputStream));
```

Then get the required element from input stream:

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputStream );

    Element element=doc.getDocumentElement();
    element.normalize();

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("your element name");
```

Comment: I can't find XMLParser

Comment: its default with android sdk package

Comment: There are so many tutorials available in online, just refer it and try it. you can refer to the links as reference                                                          https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/                                                                                          https://www.journaldev.com/10653/android-xml-parser-xmlpullparser

Comment: I'll try change xml to json and back to you

Comment: Good decision. JSON parsing is much easier than XML Parsing. try to change to JSON format.

Comment: I have done I used this library for change XML to JSON https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java thank you.